# Linear mapping in an inner product space

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having difficulty with the following problem:  Consider two inner products <,> and [,] on an inner product space V (real of dimension n).  I need to find a linear mapping such that $[L(\vec{x}),L(\vec{y})] = <\vec{x},\vec{y}>$ for all $\vec{x},\vec{y}$ in V.

What I have so far:  Let {$\vec{v_1},...,\vec{v_n}$} be an orthonormal basis for V with respect to <,>.  Then it I need to find L such that $[L(\vec{v_i}),L(\vec{v_j})] = <\vec{v_1},\vec{v_j}>$.  However, this = 0 if i and j are not equal, and 1 if i and j are equal.  From here I should be able to create a linear mapping, but I just can't seem to think my way through this.

Any pointers would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to send an orthonormal basis with respect to $\langle,\rangle$ to an orthonormal basis with respect to $[,]$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u_1,...,u_n$ be an orthonormal basis for $(V,\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$, and $v_1,....,v_n$ be an orthonormal basis for $(V,[ \cdot, \cdot ])$.

Define $L$ by $Lu_k = v_k$ and extend to $V$.

Then

$[Lx, Ly] =[ \sum_i x_i L u_i, \sum_j y_j L u_j ] = \sum_i \sum_j x_i y_j [L u_i, L u_j] = \sum_i \sum_j x_i y_j [v_i, v_j] = \sum_k x_k y_k$

and $\langle x,y \rangle = \langle \sum_i x_i u_i, \sum_j y_j u_j \rangle
 = \sum_i \sum_j x_i y_j \langle  u_i, u_j \rangle = \sum_k x_k y_k$.